# JBoss 6 deploying war file and getting error NoSuchFieldError : factoryFinder

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, session, jboss6.x

I am trying to deploy my application on JBoss 6 and I am using hibernate3, struts2 and spring3 in my application. But when I am deploying my Application it is giving error:

> INFO  [STDOUT] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: factoryFinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of errors occur when we try to change the server. The versions of libraries we are using should be compatible with the version of server.

Suppose if you are upgrading your server then you will have to update your jar dependencies as well.

The issue which you are facing is due to incompatible jar files. However it cannot be said due to which particular file it is showing this error.

You will have to trace this out at what point this exception is thrown and then that class is present in which jar file. According to that you can try to update your jar files and get it done.

As it is very late answer you might want to update to the latest versions of all jar files.

Answer (score 1):

The versions of some jars are incompatible.

One jar is expecting a field `factoryFinder` in the other jar, but it does not exist in the supplied version.

Which are the offending jars I can't tell from the information provided. But note that maybe JBoss includes a version of hibernate in its libraries, so your jar might not be loaded by the classloader.

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks for replying... I am using org.springframework.aop-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar and other similar 3.0.2 jars and hibernate3.jar.. what jar files should I try to change?

Comment: I don't know exactly. Experiment. And check what's already bundled with jboss